# How to always expand items in QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I am creating a completer myself, using ComboBox and QTreeView (for the proposal list).

```
MyComboBox::MyComboBox( QWidget *p_parent ) : QComboBox( p_parent )
{
  setEditable(true);

  m_view = new QTreeView();
  m_view->expandAll();     // this command does not work!!!

  m_view->setItemDelegate( new CompleterDelegate(m_view));
  CompleterSourceModel *m_sourceModel = new CompleterSourceModel(this);
  CompleterProxyModel *m_proxyModel = new CompleterProxyModel(this);
  m_proxyModel->setSourceModel(m_sourceModel);

  setView(m_view);
  setModel(m_proxyModel);

  connect(this, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &MyComboBox::showProposalList);
}
```

The structure of my data for the tree model here is parent-child. With the constructor above, after I put my data into the model, the children are hidden, only the parents can be seen. 
In order to see all the items (children) I have to use `m_view->expandAll()` **after** I put the data into the model. Is there any way that we can do it in constructor, so each time i put data into the model (whatever my data is), all the items (parents and children) are automatically expanded ?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to connect to the [`QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal to make sure items are expanded on a just-in-time basis.  So, immediately after setting the view's model use something like...

```
connect(m_view->model(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted,
        [this](const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)
        {

            /*
             * New rows have been added to parent.  Make sure parent
             * is fully expanded.
             */
            m_view->expandRecursively(parent);
        });
```

**Edit:** It was noted in the comments (@Patrick Parker) that simply calling `m_view->expand(parent)` will not work if the row inserted has, itself, one or more levels of descendants.  Have changed the code to use `m_view->expandRecursively(parent)` (as suggested by @m7913d) to take care of that.

Comment: Note that `QTreeView::expand` is already optimised for the case that the tree item is already expanded. So, the condition isn't needed.

Comment: One may prefer `expandRecursively`, instead of `expand`.

Comment: it doesn't work for me with qt 5.9.3 ... I call appendRow on a QStandardItemModel with an item that has a child and a grandchild. this gives me only one rowsInserted signal at parent=invalid (0,0). calling expand on an invalid parent then does nothing.

Comment: @PatrickParker Edited answer to use `QTreeView::expandRecursively` rather than `QTreeView::expand` .  Assuming I've understood you correctly, that appears to take care of the problem.

Comment: @G.M. thanks. unfortunately that doesn't help me because expandRecursively is only available in Qt 5.13. However I was able to write my own recursive helper function

Comment: Also, even in Qt 5.13 this implementation is still not good. If I pass expandRecursively with null parent index that will either expandAll or do nothing (I'd have to check the implementation to see which). The correct behavior would be to expand only the recursive children of the rows we added, and the parent of the rows we added (in this case none). It amazes me that Qt couldn't just provide an autoExpand property for this

Comment: Not sure I understand.  The current answer using `expandRecursively` was tested with both cases where the parent index was valid and also where it was null/invalid and 'appeared' to behave as expected/required.  If there is a distinct case where this isn't appropriate then it's probably worth opening a separate question.  With the usual apologies if I'm missing something here.

Comment: right. calling expandRecursively as you've shown will then perform extra work, since it is needlessly expanding all the siblings of the inserted parent row. For very large trees that could be inefficient. If we don't care about performance we could have just called `expandAll`. So this answer still has room for improvement.